# One-to-many relation database design

Tags: database

Currently I'm working on a students system, in my project i need to make each student has many courses registered in it ... What is the best way to design the database?
currently I've created a table named students which contains students info,
and a table named courses contains names of courses.
I know that the way to do that is by making a foreign key from students table references to courses table,and I've tried that but i'm confused how to that exactly.
thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds more like a many-to-many relationship. A student can participate in multiple courses, but courses will accept multiple students as well..

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
yes you are right. so how to identify that each student is registered in multiple courses in order to display the courses that the student is registered in it in his profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a table to model the many-to-many relation:

```
Students [ id | name | etc..]
Courses  [ id | name | etc.. ]
Students in Courses [ id | student_id | course_id ]
```

You can details about the relationship in there as well (in what year did the student enter the course, in what year did he/she finish, was the tuition paid etc..)

The data in these tables will look something like this:

***students***

```
Id       Name   
------   --------
S1       John
S2       Jane
S3       Mike
S4       Larry
```

***courses***

```
Id       Name   
------   --------
C1       Java for beginners
C2       C# for dummies
C3       Phyton for Noobs
```

***Student in Courses***

```
Id     CourseId StudentId   
-----  ------   --------
01     C1       S1
02     C2       S1
.....
99     C3       S3
```

You can query the data by using an inner join on the tables (pseudo code):

```
Select S.Id, S.Name, C.Id, C.Name
From Students S
Inner Join 'Students in Courses' SC ON S.Id = SC.StudentId
Inner Join Courses C ON SC.CourseId = C.Id
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply
so to make it clear for me.
lets assume that there is a course named 'Java' and it has 3 students registered in it.
so the students_in_courses table would be like this:
id | 1st_student_ID | JAVA_ID
id | 2nd_student_ID | JAVA_ID
id | 3rd_student_ID | JAVA_ID